# fastcgi-mono-server2 vs fastcgi-mono-server4

Tags: mono

Not sure if this is a silly question or not. Basically I'm figuring out how to run Mono on Linux, and I'm a Linux no0b.

I've got everything up and running, but confused about fastcgi-mono-server.

A lot of sites reference `fastcgi-mono-server2` while other sites reference `fastcgi-mono-server4`

When I run:

`fastcgi-mono-server /version`

fastcgi-mono-server2.exe 2.10.0.0

I get the same version number for both.

If I look at the Mono version

Mono JIT compiler version 2.10.8.1

I'm wondering if the version on the mono-server corresponds to the mono version, and not the mono-server version.

Is `fastcgi-mono-server4` just a newer version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fastcgi-serverN means the .NET version, at least that what you see in here:

http://packages.debian.org/sid/mono-fastcgi-server2 says it runs .NET 2.0

http://packages.debian.org/sid/mono-fastcgi-server4 says it runs .NET 4.0

Comment: Ahhh I had an inkling that was the case but I couldn't find any information (mostly because I didn't know where to look and Google mostly gave setup/problems with them) Thanks a lot!!